# What is the probable reason for QtDCM compilation fail?

Tags: c++, qt, build, cmake, dcmtk

`QtDCM` compile fails. I did all as it described in this [manual](https://qtdcm.github.io/step2page.html), `DCMTK` and `ITK` was compiled without any trouble, but when I try to compile `QtDCM`, it fails with errors:

```
2>QtDcmFindScu.cpp
2>D:\CPP\qtdcm\src\QtDcmFindScu.cpp(197): error C2259: 'QtDcmFindCallback': cannot instantiate abstract class
2>D:\CPP\qtdcm\src\QtDcmFindScu.cpp(197): note: due to following members:
2>D:\CPP\qtdcm\src\QtDcmFindScu.cpp(197): note: 'void DcmFindSCUCallback::callback(T_DIMSE_C_FindRQ *,int &,T_DIMSE_C_FindRSP *,DcmDataset *)': is abstract
2>D:\CPP\dcmtk-3.6.4\dcmnet\include\dcmtk/dcmnet/dfindscu.h(96): note: see declaration of 'DcmFindSCUCallback::callback'
2>D:\CPP\qtdcm\src\QtDcmFindScu.cpp(198): error C2664: 'OFCondition DcmFindSCU::performQuery(const char *,unsigned int,const char *,const char *,const char *,E_TransferSyntax,T_DIMSE_BlockingMode,int,Uint32,bool,bool,unsigned int,DcmFindSCUExtractMode,int,OFList<OFString> *,DcmFindSCUCallback *,OFList<OFString> *,const char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 13 from 'bool' to 'DcmFindSCUExtractMode'
2>D:\CPP\qtdcm\src\QtDcmFindScu.cpp(203): note: Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
2>QtDcmMoveScu.cpp
2>D:\CPP\qtdcm\src\QtDcmMoveScu.cpp(373): error C2039: 'unlock': is not a member of 'GlobalDcmDataDictionary'
2>D:\CPP\dcmtk-3.6.4\dcmdata\include\dcmtk/dcmdata/dcdict.h(216): note: see declaration of 'GlobalDcmDataDictionary'
2>D:\CPP\qtdcm\src\QtDcmMoveScu.cpp(775): error C2660: 'DU_findSOPClassAndInstanceInDataSet': function does not take 4 arguments
2>D:\CPP\dcmtk-3.6.4\dcmnet\include\dcmtk/dcmnet/diutil.h(110): note: see declaration of 'DU_findSOPClassAndInstanceInDataSet'
2>D:\CPP\qtdcm\src\QtDcmMoveScu.cpp(965): error C2660: 'ASC_getAPTitles': function does not take 4 arguments
2>D:\CPP\dcmtk-3.6.4\dcmnet\include\dcmtk/dcmnet/assoc.h(328): note: see declaration of 'ASC_getAPTitles'
```

Is it troubles in library src?
Is it possible that I did mistake in `CMake-GUI` when configured it?

I want to compile `QtDCM` library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect error message to be in the question post itself, not linked. Please. [edit] your question and paste error log into it. You may format the log with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the QtDCM project has not been updated since November 2011, so I would suggest that you also download the DCMTK version that was available at that time, i.e. the [3.6.0 release](https://dcmtk.org/download/dcmtk/dcmtk360/).

Comment: Indeed, it seems that QtDCM switched to DCMTK 3.6.2 (https://github.com/qtdcm/qtdcm/commit/0c365f6) but you are using a newer version of this DICOM toolkit? This is probably the reason for the compiler errors listed in your question above (since the API changed between releases).